# How to signal the event that two shapes have touched? Java

Tags: java, events, actionlistener, graphics2d

So I have a Blob shape, which implements MoveableShape.

```
public interface MoveableShape
{
   void draw(Graphics2D g2);
   void translate(int dx, int dy);
}
```

Let's say an instance of a Blob, b1, hits another Blob, b2. Once it hits the other blob, I want it to reverse its direction. How would I signal this in java? Up until now, this is what I've been doing to move it normally:

```
Timer t = new Timer(DELAY, new
     ActionListener()
     {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
           b1.translate(1, 0);
           label.repaint();
        }
     });
  t.start();
```

And I sincerely believe there is a more efficient way to do this rather than replacing those 6th and 7th lines with this:

```
b1.translate(speed, 0);
label.repaint();
if(b1.getX()==b2.getX()) { speed = -speed }
```

I apologize for not documenting every detail, but you should get the general gist from that.  Is it possible to add some sort of custom event to b1 to reverse its direction, or something like that? Moreover, is it possible to do this with an ActionListener? Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to real collision detection of 2D shapes, or is it enough to compare X coordinates as in your example? The coordinate comparison is obviously much (MUCH) simpler, but you'll probably have visible overlap in the shapes before you reverse direction.

Comment: @eaj The latter is fine. My only issue is with the constant if statement being executed repeatedly in the actionPerformed. Also, there is a .getWidth() option for this class, so I won't have overlap in the end (I just forgot to include that in the comparison).

Answer (score 0):

You can of course fire a custom event when the shapes collide, but you still have to write the code to detect the collision. If you're dissatisfied with your current approach, maybe `Shape.intersects()` will help (assuming you're subclassing `Shape`).

However, unless you need to notify other listeners of the collision, there's probably no point in firing off another event to handle it; it makes sense to do it with the animation code.

If the collision detection becomes complex enough that it's likely to impact performance, you'll probably need to shuffle that off into another thread. It sounds like you're not likely to encounter that particular complication, though.